# Why are three parameters required to express rotation in 3 dimension?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, mathematics, geometry

We know that in spherical coordinates angle $\theta$ and $\phi$ (two angles)are enough to express three dimensional rotation of matrix. But to express rotation mathematically as a transformation matrix we require three angles. But intuitively I expect only two parameters for rotation matrix based on the knowledge of spherical coordinates. What is wrong here?

Comment: Two angles represent the direction of the axis (in spherical coordinates) about which the rotation is to be performed. The third angle is the magnitude of the rotation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed out by lemon, two angles are enough to specify a *direction* in a three dimensional coordinate system, but another is needed to specify a complete coordinate transformation.  You can think of a rotation transformation in three dimensions as a mapping between two different coordinate systems.  Two angles are needed to specify the relative pointing between the two z axes, but another is needed to specify the relative pointing of the x axis.  Without this third angle the x and y axes could lie anywhere in the plane perpendicular to the new z axis.

Comment: How many parameters would be needed to fully specify a rotation transformation in R^4?

Comment: will it be ${}^n C_2 = 1/2 n(n-1)$ for $R^n$? so 6.You can make rotations on ${}^n C_2$ planes in $n$-dimensional space, which coincides with the number of generators of SO(n).

Comment: @FireLizzard: Rotations are orthogonal transformations, that is $R \cdot R^T = 1$. This gives $n(n+1)/2$ constrains to a $n \times n$ matrix which therefore leaves $n^2 - n(n+1)/2$ free parameters. For $n=4$ one has 6 parameters. Take for example the homogeneous lorentz group, which is nothing more than usual rotation in a (pseudo)-euclidean space with 4 dimensions (3 boost parameter + 3 space rotation parameter).

Comment: In other words, $N(N-1)/2$ parameters are needed to specify a rotation in $N$-dimensional space. The only case where this is equal to $N$ is N=3. As noted above, six parameters are needed to describe rotation in four dimensional space. Also noteworthy: only one parameter is needed to describe rotation in two dimensional space.

Comment: Awesome explanation, thank you!